# RabbitMQ - Sending the same message more than once to the queue (Some fail)

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, message-queue

So guys, I'm using **RabbitMQ** and when I send the same message more than once per second of difference, I notice that some are not arriving. Does anyone know if RabbitMQ discards the new message with the same content if it still exists in the queue?

Answer (score 1):

You can send as many messages with the same message body (payload / content) to RabbitMQ as you want and they will be stored. The message body (payload / content) does not have to be unique.